# python celery monitoring events not being triggered

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a following project directory:

```
azima:
    __init.py
    main.py
    tasks.py
    monitor.py
```

tasks.py

```
from .main import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

main.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('azima', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', include=['azima.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

monitor.py

```
from .main import app

def my_monitor(app):
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_failed_tasks(event):
        state.event(event)
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

        print(f'TASK FAILED: {task.name}[{task.uuid}]')

    def announce_succeeded_tasks(event):
        print('task succeeded')
        state.event(event)
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

        print(f'TASK SUCCEEDED: {task.name}[{task.uuid}]')

    def worker_online_handler(event):
        state.event(event)
        print("New worker gets online")
        print(event['hostname'], event['timestamp'], event['freq'], event['sw_ver'])

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
                'task-failed': announce_failed_tasks,
                'task-succeeded': announce_succeeded_tasks,
                'worker-online': worker_online_handler,
                '*': state.event,
        })
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app = Celery('azima')
    my_monitor(app)
```

Started celery worker with

```
celery -A azima.main worker -l INFO
```

And started `monitor.py` with

```
python -m azima.monitor
```

But Only `worker-online` event is being triggered, while other events like `task-succeeded` is not triggered or handled.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable worker `task-` group events with [cli option](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/cli.html#celery-worker) `-E` or `--task-events` and try to capture all events:

```py
def my_monitor(app):
    def on_event(event):
        print("Event.type", event.get('type'))

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={'*': on_event})
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, Celery workers do not send events. However, like most of the useful features, it can be configured by enabling the [worker_send_task_events](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-send-task-events) in your config, or running Celery worker(s) with the `-E` flag.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing your code to [flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s [code](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/flower/events.py#L148):

```
try_interval = 1
while True:
    try:
        try_interval *= 2

        with self.capp.connection() as conn:
            recv = EventReceiver(conn,
                                    handlers={"*": self.on_event},
                                    app=self.capp)
            try_interval = 1
            logger.debug("Capturing events...")
            recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        try:
            import _thread as thread
        except ImportError:
            import thread
        thread.interrupt_main()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Failed to capture events: '%s', "
                        "trying again in %s seconds.",
                        e, try_interval)
        logger.debug(e, exc_info=True)
        time.sleep(try_interval)
```

There are 2 differences:

1. celery `app` is missing in your `EventReceiver`.
2. Infinity loop (`while True`) although I assume `capture` method is blocking and waiting for events and the loop is just in case of an error.